# What information can the merchant see about you when you pay with Paypal?

Tags: paypal, online-payment, security, identity-theft, privacy

Just paid a shady looking seller using Paypal thinking that Paypal could protect me. Bought a digital product, received, but rethought the whole thing and now I think I don’t trust the seller to not misuse information they may be able to get from that transaction.

Can they see:

1. The name on my Paypal account
2. The address on my Paypal account
3. The phone number on my Paypal account
4. The full card number (PAN) of the card used to pay via Paypal

**Or any other information that you would think is relevant?**

I am worried about them using my info to commit fraud, sign me up for 3rd party stuff using my name without my knowledge, or do similar bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can they see:
>
> - The name on my Paypal account

Yes.

> - The address on my Paypal account

Yes.

> - The phone number on my Paypal account

Yes.

> - The full card number (PAN) of the card used to pay via Paypal

No.

Paypal only protects the thing you can most easily change in this list.

Comment: For phone number, sellers can *optionally* require this. It's not the default.

Comment: @ceejayoz I had an ebay seller call me on my phone and yell at me for less than perfect feedback that I've left, so whether it is default or they need to ask for it to get it doesn't really matter